# Зачем участники исправляют то, что не требует исправления?

Tags: поддержка, правки, предлагаемые-правки

Например, вот этот: [Как работает следующий код?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1070441/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4?noredirect=1#comment1836755_1070441)

Мне предложили убрать `class A; class B; class C;` и оставить только `class B;`, якобы для читабельности кода. Зачем это?

Comment: заметка: это действие было произведено не модераторами. Откат к предыдущей версии, если вы не согласны – разумное решение. Но конструктивные правки - откатывать не стоит.

Comment: Однако, там, больше вроде вопрос просто в форматировании кода отступами. Вандализмом, вроде не пахнет.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно [историю правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1070441/revisions). То что вы описываете в вопросе не соответствует действительности. Укажите пожалуйста номер ревизии и что там было изменено.

Comment: Да я был не прав,но это все равно ничего не меняет. Было в строчку а вы записали в столбик. Не вижу смысла.

Comment: Это был не я. Правку предложил другой участник, а я только её проверял. 1) Если бы только декларация классов поменялась с одной на три строчки, то правка была бы отклонена как незначительная.   
2) В функции не хватало отступов, что ухудшало читаемость и правка была принята.    
Если вы как автор не согласны с правкой, то вы даже после её принятия можете правку откатить до нужной ревизии. Откатить, значит воспользоваться кнопкой [откат], а не пытаться вручную вернуть старое.

Comment: " они просто извините за выражение страдают херней" они улучшили ваш вопрос. А вы зачем-то склеиваете строки, меняете местами классы, задаете вопрос на мете. Ну и кто чем страдает?

Comment: Вообщем у редактора была мотивация что-то типа "о, код без отступов! читать невозможно! Поправлю отступы, ну и заодно весь стиль изменю на традиционный". А ваша какая? "Моё! не трожь!" ?

Comment: Код в первой редакции даже прочитать толком нельзя, не говоря уже о том, что объяснить как он работает.

Comment: Свой - могу. И код коллег могу. И много других кодов могу. Потому что, представьте себе, и я и они придерживаются общепринятых норм и соглашений. А код, автор которого на эти соглашения плюет и тем самым показывает свое неуважение к другим, мне читать не хочется. И уверяю вас, как только начнете работать с другими людьми в нормальной организации, писать такой код вас очень быстро отучат.

Comment: @4per, да действительно! Задавать вопросы на мете это пустая трата времени и нерв так как тут только такие люди и сидят которые кроме того как редактировать читабельный код больше ничего не умеют.

Answer (score 7):

По пунктам:

1. Это сделал не модератор, а обычный участник.
2. Другие участники в очереди подтвердили эту правку.
3. Часть правок улучшило сообщение (отступы лишние убраны и т.п).
4. Правки с переносом на новую строку определений классов - субъективно. Если вам, как автору, именно эта часть правок не нравится, то вы, безусловно, можете вернуть эту часть назад как было.
5. Но, всё же, раз участники в очереди утвердили правки, то, вероятно, они действительно улучшают сообщение.